# Bar and stacked bars on one plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Good evening, can anybody help with plotting. I have some data like this:

```
    DF <- data.frame(
        country_dest=c("Russia", "Germany", "Ukraine" ,"Kazakhstan", 
        "United States", "Italy", "Israel", "Belarus"),
        SumTotal=c(7076562,2509617,1032325,680137,540630,359030,229186,217623)
    )
```

It is not a big deal to plot it with separate 8 bars, but i am wondering to know is it possible to make a plot with 3 bars, where first bar will be with data of Russia (for example) second will be stacked bar of Germany, Ucraine, Kazakhstan, US and Italy maybe with some legend to understand who is who and third  stacked bar of Belarus and Israel.

In internet I have found a solution to create new DF with 0 values, but didn't quite understand.

Than you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you will need to add grouping information to your data. Then it becomes straightforward. Here's one strategy

```
#define groups
grp <-c("Russia"=1, "Germany"=2, "Ukraine"=2,"Kazakhstan"=2, 
        "United States"=2, "Italy"=2, "Israel"=3, "Belarus"=3)
DF$grp<-grp[as.character(DF$country_dest)]

#ensure plotting order
DF$country_dest <- factor(DF$country_dest, levels=DF$country_dest)

#draw plot
ggplot(DF, aes(x=grp, y=SumTotal, fill=country_dest)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

This will give you

[image]

You might wish to give your groups a more descriptive label.

Comment: it works, but i had to swap the line of codes DF$country_dest <- factor(DF$country_dest, levels=DF$country_dest)   then   DF$grp<-grp[DF$country_dest], and gained success, thank you for you help)