# With both stacked and dodged bars, how can you remove dodge-bar elements from legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Thanks to [combine stacked bars and dodged bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465127/bar-and-stacked-bars-on-one-plot-in-ggplot2), I created the plot below using the data frame shown.  But now, since the axis titles name the bars, how can I remove the legend elements other than for the one stacked bar?  That is, can the legend show only the segments of the Big8 bar?

```
> dput(combo)
structure(list(firm = structure(c(12L, 1L, 11L, 13L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("Avg.", "Co", "Firm1", 
"Firm2", "Firm3", "Firm4", "Firm5", "Firm6", "Firm7", "Firm8", 
"Median", "Q1", "Q3"), class = "factor"), metric = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Avg.", 
"Big8", "Co", "Median", "Q1", "Q3"), class = "factor"), value = c(0.0012, 
0.0065, 0.002, 0.0036, 0.0065, 0.000847004466666667, 0.000658907411111111, 
0.0002466389, 8.41422555555556e-05, 8.19149222222222e-05, 7.97185555555556e-05, 
7.82742555555556e-05, 7.56679888888889e-05), grp = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Q1", 
"Avg.", "Median", "Co", "Big8", "Q3"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("firm", 
"metric", "value", "grp"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the plotting code.

```
ggplot(combo, aes(x=grp, y=value, fill=firm)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

The plot, which ideally would have a smaller set of elements in the legend.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can manually set the `breaks` for `scale_fill_discrete`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(combo, aes(x=grp, y=value, fill=firm)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    labs(x = "", y = "") +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
    scale_fill_discrete(breaks = combo$firm[combo$metric=="Big8"])
```

[image]

I'm not 100% sure which labels you want to keep, but a manually entered vector, `combo$firm` and `combo$metric` will all work.